# XPath to count the number of Attributes in an XML Element

Tags: xml, xpath

Is it possible to get number of attributes in XML element using XPath?

```
<ABC xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

From this example line I want to get back value 2.

If it is not possible is any other way to check by XPath that namespace was defined and there are no other prefixes defined in XML?

Answer (score 2):

To get number of **attributes** you can use below `XPath` expression

```
/ABC/count(@*)
```

while to get count of **namespace declarations** you might use

```
/ABC/count(namespace::*)-1
```

but I'm not sure that this is the best way...

**Update**

In current case this should work as

```
xmlns:xsd=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema + 
xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org /2001/XMLSchema-instance + 
xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" - 1 = 3 - 1 = 2
```

But as @Michael Kay has pointed out `/ABC/count(namespace::*)-1` will count also namespace declarations that might be defined in ancestors... So this solution might be used only if you don't expect namespace declarations in other ancestor elements

As for your second question, if you want to check whether some particular prefix, e.g. `xsd`, was defined and it's the only defined prefix, you might try something like:

```
//ABC/namespace::*[name()="xsd"] and //ABC/count(namespace::*[name()="xsd"])+ 1 = //ABC/count(namespace::*)
```

This will return `Boolean` value

Comment: Actually `count(namespace::*)` will count the number of in-scope namespaces, i.e. it will also include namespaces inherited from ancestor elements.